# How do I redirect Qemu guest console=tty0 to host stdin/stdout?

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu

I have a linux kernel that has the following configuration options:

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE="console=tty0 init=/init"
CONFIG_CMDLINE_OVERRIDE=y
```

I execute Qemu with something like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -kernel my-vmlinuz
```

This (correctly) shows me no output because `-nographic` implicitly attaches the guest `ttyS0` (not `tty0`) to the host `stdin`/`stdout`. How can I tell Qemu to attach the guest `tty0` to the host `stdin`/`stdout`?

References:

- https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CMDLINE.html
- https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CMDLINE_BOOL.html
- https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CMDLINE_OVERRIDE.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. The virtual terminals (`tty1` etc.) are implemented on top of the VGA text mode, which basically gives the system a memory-mapped array of characters (+ attributes). The kernel then writes to that array as it wants. File streams like `stdout` however, are inherently linear, so they're not entirely compatible.

What you can do, however, is to use `qemu -curses` to have a view into the guest's text mode VGA output; or, put `console=ttyS0` in the kernel command line instead to have the guest use the serial port as console. (You may also need to configure `grub` to use the serial port.)

Comment: I'm not using any bootloader (beyond what is emulated by qemu), and I don't control the kernel command line. The `-curses` option looks promising, though --- assuming I can figure out how to build qemu to support it.

Comment: @rubicks, ah yes, you had `-kernel` there. But in that case, can't QEMU set the kernel command line too? There's the `-append <cmdline>` switch in my qemu manual for that. But I don't know how that works together with a builtin command line (does it override or append).

Comment: @ikkachu, `CONFIG_CMDLINE_OVERRIDE=y` causes the kernel to ignore any given command-line parameters.

Comment: Note: -curses was renamed to `-display curses`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work for you:

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8 init=/init"
```

This comes from [tldp's remote serial console HOWTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel-grub.html)

See also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/471719/how-to-start-qemu-directly-in-the-console-not-in-curses-or-sdl)